# Parallel authentication with Membership and Forms

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, membership

I have an application with a backend and frontend area :

• the backend area is for the admin, using a form authentication (login informations defined in the web.config file)

```
    <forms loginUrl="/admin/account/logon/" timeout="525600">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
            <user name="login" password="password"/>
        </credentials>
    </forms>
```

• and the frontend is for the user who does not need to log in since he uses the front to get a new password. I need to log the user with his membership datas from his email :

```
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(login, password))
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login, true);
```

but when i do that, it replaces the user in my backend area (the one for the admin)

How can I seperate the two authentications with .NET ?

Comment: Have a look at roles. You could have a single authentication module and allow access via these roles.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i did not think about that; I'll get a look a this. Thank you.

Comment: Or use custom authorize attributes to protect some endpoints while leaving other's open or protected in different ways. Also, look into properly subclassing your own MembershipProvider. That will simplify and clean much of this up.